# What is meant by when we say more than two (say 4) particles are entangled

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

I understand the entanglement of a pair of particles which known to show three kinds of correlation - (consider the property entangled is spin)

1. Anti correlation - when two particles are measured in same angle They always have opposite outcome.
2. Statistical correlation of SQUARE of sin((A-B)/2) when two particles are measured at angles A and B.
3. Statistical correlation of 50/50 when one particle is measured numerous times at any specific angle.

How is entanglement of say 4 particle, described in terms of correlations? Can an odd number of particles get entangled too, or it has to be always an even number?

I know about mathematical superposition. What I am looking for is can it be described in terms of correlations in a similar way as the pair entanglement is described above?, or it is too complex to describe it like that and must use mathematical equations to even describe what the measurement results are going to look like.

Comment: There are entangled states with the statistics you describe.   There are other entangled states (for two particles) with other statistics.  If you want to know the statistics associated with a  three or four particle state, you have to first specify which state you're talking about.

Comment: based on your response, I'd say the first thing you have to do is learn what a quantum state is.

Comment: @WillO: OK, I agree spin is a property, not a state. Irrespective of that, can the 4 particle entanglement be described in terms of statistics in a similar way a pair entanglement is?

Comment: There is not an automatic opposition at the pair level but a statistic particularly with angles far from 0 and pi/2 but also with them.

Comment: yes more than 2 entities might be entangled. Zeilinger published about 3, Einstein about billions ( B-E condensates ). Pairs are interesting because it is easiest to highlight the entanglement, the difference with the classical statistic being maximum

Comment: @igael I don't think BECs are necessarily entangled.

Comment: @aquirdturtle : I learned it , even if it is not the same entanglement than for spins ... do you have a link to a modern interpretation ? ( sorry for the sidetrack )

Comment: for 3 ( odd ) [Observation of three-photon Greenberger-Horne-Zeilinger entanglement](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9810035) .

Comment: @kpv:  You ask if a 4 particle entanglement can be described in terms of statistics in a similar way to a pair entanglement:  Answer: Of course the state cannot be described in terms of statistics, for either a four particle state OR a two particle state.  You can derive the statistics from the state, but the state contains more information than just those statistics.

Comment: @WillO: I do not understand the states that well. But if state defines the correlation, then can you derive the state I am talking about from the statistics that I have listed? Please also name the state if possible.

Comment: @kpv:  No, for the fourth time, I cannot derive the state from the statistics you have listed, because the statistics are not enough to determine the state.  As for "naming the state if possible", I choose "Fred".

Comment: @WillO: Do not know what you meant by Fred. Any way,  
I am reading about states so that I can name the state, if you can not. Another link if helps - It is the state to which the Bell's theorem is famously applied and violated with greatest statistical difference for entangled pairs

Comment: When populal science talk about quantum entanglement, spooky action at a distance (or absence of it), Bell's inequality .. and so on, they do not mention the state. They talk about this statistics. Seems some state is assumed there. For example, watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZuvK-od647c

Comment: @igael Suppose you just have $10^8$ bosons all perfectly in the ground state of some harmonic oscillator. The state is symmetrized, and is definitely a BEC, but the state can be written as a product state, so I don't think it's entangled.

Comment: @kdv:  An example of a state that produces the statistics you describe is $(1/\sqrt{2})(U\otimes U+ D\otimes D)$.  Another is $(1/\sqrt{2})(U\otimes U-D\otimes D)$.  Another is $(1/\sqrt{2})(U\otimes U-iD\otimes D)$.  If you give me a state, I can tell you the statistics.  If you give me the statistics, I can give you some candidates for the state.  In the four-particle case, you are giving me neither the state nor the statistics, so  I can't tell you anything about either without reading your mind.

Comment: ...and also here.

Comment: @peterh: I would let this one delete.  Thsnks

Comment: @peterh: I renewed this one too, as it was just a click.

Comment: @kpv If it has an upvoted answer, it won't be deleted automatically.

Answer (score 7):

Yours seems to be an odd way of defining entanglement. A simple guideline I use is that a state of 2 particles is entangled if you can't separate the total state into a product state of the two individual particles.  Entanglement of more particles follows naturally from this guideline, as not being able to separate out any of the three individual particle states from each other.

Of course if you want to get specific you can find numerous ways of quantizing entanglement, for example by looking at the Schmidt decomposition of the state. In this case the question generally switches from "are these particles entangled" to "how much entanglement is there in this system".

An odd number of particles can *definitely* be entangled. In fact, you can have entangled states that don't even have a definite particle number.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43335/discussion-on-answer-by-aquirdturtle-what-is-meant-by-when-we-say-more-than-two).