# Quantum entanglement correlations - role of probability

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

Suppose in an entanglement experiment, angles of measurement are fixed. QM predicts that $50$% pairs will measure same spin. Ignoring other details, just consider QM predicted value is $50$%. Then does QM also predicts the distribution of same spin pairs? If so, is that predicted distribution any different from that of any other event with $50$% probability, like tossing a coin?

To clarify further - say probability of getting a head in a coin toss is $50$%. If we toss the coin $100$ times, probability says - expected number of $10$ consecutive heads is = $(100 - 9)*(.5)^{10}$. Would this be also the expected number of $10$ consecutive same spin pairs out of $100$ pairs with same spin pair prediction at $50$%. Please ignore the fact that $100$ is a small number for entanglement. The question is just about the concept.

Further clarification -

As far as state is concerned, you may consider/assume any state. Only thing is that the number of same spin pairs is predicted at 50%. I said 50 because it can be compared with a coin toss. The real question is - given a prediction of 50%, is expected number of m consecutive same spin pairs, same as the expected number of m consecutive heads in a coin toss. The probability of getting a same spin pair and that of getting a head being same. Total number of entangled pairs measured also same as total number of coin tosses.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "are the predictions based only upon probability"? And what a "distribution of correlation" is?

Comment: @knzhou: I edited to take that confusion away.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by "50% pairs will be correlated", because correlation is a statistical property that applies to many observations, not a single one. Are you saying "50% of the time the spins will point in the same direction"?

Comment: @knzhou: Edited again,

Comment: What are you assuming about these 200 particles?  Is their state of the form $A\otimes B\otimes C....$ where each of $A$, $B$, etc is an entangled state for a particle pair?  Or something else?  Are $A$, $B$, $C$ all the same?  Or something else?  And exactly what measurement are you proposing?  Etc etc.

Comment: @WillO: I have mentioned spin measurement. As far as state is concerned, you may consider/assume any state. Only thing is that the number of same spin pairs is predicted at 50%. I said 50 because it can be compared with a coin toss. The real question is - given a prediction, is expected number of m consecutive same spin pairs, same as the expected number of m consecutive heads in a coin toss. The probability of getting a same spin pair and that of getting a head being same.

Comment: @WillO: 100 entangled pairs are measured (spin) and 100 tosses are done with a coin.

Comment: I *really* don't understand the question. The title has "entanglement" in it, but the body just seems to ask if by "probability" in quantum mechanics we relaly mean a frequentist probability.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: you are right about "but the body just seems to ask if by "probability" in quantum mechanics we relaly mean a frequentist probability". Could you please then answer it as you stated? The reason I have entanglement in there is 1) The question came to my mind while analysing entanglement data. 2)  Statistical correlation of Entanglement is also supposed to be probabilistic.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: The question is clear, and has two good answers and one of then has already been accepted by OP. I do not understand your out of way effort to put the question on hold when it already has accepted answer. That means someone was able to understand the question and even answer it. If you voted hold before it was answered by other people, please review it again and remove the hold.

Comment: @sammygerbil: The question is clear, and has two good answers and one of then has already been accepted by OP. I do not understand your out of way effort to put the question on hold when it already has accepted answer. That means someone was able to understand the question and even answer it. If you voted hold before it was answered by other people, please review it again and remove the hold.

Comment: @heather: The question is clear, and has two good answers and one of then has already been accepted by OP. I do not understand your out of way effort to put the question on hold when it already has accepted answer. That means someone was able to understand the question and even answer it. If you voted hold before it was answered by other people, please review it again and remove the hold.

Comment: @knzhou: ok, so I clarified it twice in response to your comments, could you please review it now and remove your hold

Comment: @kpv:  In answer to my question you said "you may assume any state".  Given that, the answer to your question is "you could get any distribution" --- e.g. you might get 10 consecutive heads with probability $(.5)^10$, or you might get 10 consecutive heads with probability $1/2$, or pretty much anything else.  If you ask a question with no clear answer, and if you double down on that in the comments, then your question is going to get closed as "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: @Willow: At the same time, I said consider the probability = 50%. Anyway, your decision, hope it is a fair one. States are going to be used for calculating the probability which I already gave you.

Comment: You should vote to reopen your question also here.

Comment: This question is nowhere near ready for reopening (cc @peterh). How does the body of the question relate **at all** with entanglement? Are the successive coin tosses measurements of entangled systems? If so, that needs to be directly specified. If not, then all mentions of entanglement need to be removed. And, in any case, your statement that the state of the system does not matter for making predictions is profoundly puzzling and very much flawed: you specify the state, and we tell you the properties. "Use any state" is hogwash.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: I think I got pretty good idea about you guys. The question is very clear, even has two answers, one of them is accepted. The coin example is   introduced as a clarification, and it is obvious from the question. This is really really weak and defensive for a scientific community.  I am not asking to open any of my questions. I do not need to know any more about the hollowness, it is already confirmed beyond doubt. Everyone comes up with some or other explanation, it is more like a religious community. It is not meant for me to argue this hollow.

Comment: Let me also add that  (cc @BobZ)  (cc @JohnRennie) BobZ and JohnRennie have been reasonable and neutral as per my interaction. I kind of agree with JohnRennie that one of my questions may not be considered a physics question and he also reasonably said it can be individual's interpretation.

Comment: OK, fair enough, I thought you [were](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9099/) asking for your questions to be reopened, and indeed this one can definitely be brought to a shape that's useful for other people, but if you want to drop them then that's up to you. I do find it curious, though that you seem perfectly happy to throw blame just about everywhere except on the possibility that your questions do in fact reflect a pretty deep lack of understanding of the formalism you're challenging.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: OK, if you see, there is a sequence in my questions. This one first asks if entanglement correlations should behave probabilistic or not. Then the next one asks - this is the observation in data, does it appear probabilistic, or not. Yes, I lack the deep understanding of the formalism. But there are enough people who possess that understanding, including people in this community. And for such people, my question should be really easy to understand, provided there is an openness for challenge. Also, I am not challenging, just clearing doubts so it makes sense.

Comment: @kpv I do want to ask you to have a good read of [this](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/18491) before you charge around with accusations of "religiousness". You say you want to learn the formalism, but when you were given an [answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/270783) that actually gets entanglement right, you essentially dismissed the viewpoint outright. In any case: badly-posed questions derail the conversation, make it much harder to have a specific thing to discuss, and they are below useful for future visitors: that is why we ask that you fix the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44952/discussion-between-kpv-and-emilio-pisanty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question is yes.

It is not possible to derive this result from within quantum theory, rather it is stated as a postulate (the Born rule) that the mod square of the coefficients in wave function expansions should be interpreted as a probability, with all the usual implications of probability from statistical physics.

As such strictly the wave function of a system has no meaning for a single measurement but can only be given meaning in the context of measurements of an ensemble of identically prepared systems, in which case the probability is *defined* as a frequency of results of a large sample of runs.

The Statistical (or Ensemble) Interpretation of quantum mechanics formalises this idea, and can be viewed as the minimalist interpretation consistent with the mathematical formalism. It is an open question whether there is an underlying theory from which outcomes of individual experiments could be predicted.

Edit: There have been attempts to derive the Born rule, for example from Envariance (http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0405161) or from the Many Worlds Interpretation. It is debatable to what extent these arguments are circular.

Comment: Thank you Bruce. Can you please provide some links to material/postulate that says "the mod square of the coefficients in wave function expansions should be interpreted as a probability, with all the usual implications of probability from statistical physics."

Comment: It is unclear how deep you wish to go into this. Perhaps read Born Rule in Wikipedia and follow the links in the interpretation section, then come back with a more specific question.

Comment: I just need a credible source that states what you wrote, or very close to it because this is exactly what I was looking for. I.e. "the mod square of the coefficients in wave function expansions should be interpreted as a probability, with all the usual implications of probability from statistical physics."

Comment: The Born rule is actually (arguably, at least) derivable.

Comment: @aquirdturtle we will get in trouble if we discuss that here. If you can formulate as a precise physics question as a separate question then that may be allowed

Comment: Wasn't so much a question; I was reffering to this: http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0405161

Comment: The details of the derivation are a bit above me atm, I just thought I'd point out that the statement "[Born's Rule] is stated as a postulate" seems to be debatable.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you aren't really talking about entanglement (although perhaps a description of entanglement sparked this question).

Typically when people discuss probabilities in relation to superpositions or entanglement, they mean "if I performed this experiment many times, I'd measure this outcome X% of the time". The particles in such separate experiments are not correlated, and so the probabilities associated with such **measurements** can be treated and combined classically (like coin flips) without regard for the fact that quantum mechanics was the source of the probabilities.

---

Although this perhaps wasn't the point of your question, when thinking about quantum probabilities in relation to classical probabilities, it's important to remember that despite their **measurements** looking similar, the the **state** of a quantum system before the measurement is very different from it's classical analog. For example, if you measure the spin of an electron, it could be up or down with respect to your measurement, and if you prepare your electron correctly it could be a 50%-50% probability for each.

Although it sounds similar, this is **very different** from a classical coin-flip. Suppose you flip your coin and it lands. Before you look at it, your coin **is either** heads or tails, you just don't know which. Saying it's 50%-50% here is a statement about your ignorance of the state of the coin.

For a (properly prepared) electron, before you look (i.e. measure) the electron's spin, it is **neither** up nor down, **unlike** the coin. It is in a quantum-mechanical super-position of both up and down. *After* the measurement it is in one of the two states (with the given probability) but before it was in neither. This probably sounds pedantic, but the difference is very real. *Quantum interference* effects are entirely a result of this distinction. For example, look up electron diffraction or the HOM effect.

Comment: OK, the electrons may be in superposition before they are measured. My question is about the results. Measuring 100 electrons with 50% up probability. What is the expected number of 10 consecutive up spin electrons? That is the question. I have given that number for 10 consecutive heads in 100 tosses in my question. Is the expected number of 10 consecutive up spin electrons, same as 10 consecutive heads?

Comment: Yes. The probability there works the same (unless the 100 different electrons are all entangled with each other, but I'm pretty sure that's not what you were going for).

Comment: That is why I asked the question using entanglement example. Two electrons in a pair are entangled with each other. But the 100 pairs are created and measured at different times, so there is no entanglement from one pair to another. In your scanario, the 100 electrons are independent i.e not entangled. Also, could you please revise your answer so I can upvote it. I will wait few more answers before accepting an answer.